# Exercise 1.69 of Megginson's “An Introduction to Banach Space Theory”.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, linear-transformations

Preliminaries:

Definition 1: Let X be a metric space and $M\subset{X}$ be a subset. Then M is said to be

(a) rare (or nowhere dense) in X, if its closure $\overline{M}$ has no interior point;

(b) meager (or of the first category) in X, if M is the union of countably many sets each of which is rare in X;

(c) nonmeager (or of the second category) in X, if M is not meager in X.

Theorem 1 (Baire's Category Theorem): If a metric space $X\neq\emptyset$ is complete, then it is nonmeager in itself. Consequently, if $X\neq\emptyset$ is complete and $$X=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}{A_{k}},\phantom{a}A_{k}\phantom{a}\text{closed,}$$ then at least one $A_{k}$ contains a nonempty open subset of X.

Exercise 1.69: Let X be a normed space and $X^{*}=B(X,\mathbb{F}).$ Suppose that $(x_{n})$ is a sequence in X such that $\sum_{n}{x^{*}x_{n}}$ converges whenever $x^{*}\in X^{*}.$ Show that the mapping $x^{*}\in X^{*}\longmapsto\sum_{n}{x^{*}x_{n}}$ is a bounded linear functional on $X^{*}.$

Attempt: Let $T\colon X^{*}\to \mathbb{F}$ be the mapping given by $T(x^{*})=\sum_{n}{x^{*}x_{n}}.$ Let $x^{*}\in X^{*}.$ Notice that $$|T(x^{*})|=\left|\sum_{n}{x^{*}x_{n}}\right|\leq\sum_{n}{|x^{*}x_{n}|}\leq |x^{*}|\sum_{n}{||x_{n}||}.$$ If the series $ \sum_ {n} {|| x_ {n} ||} $ is convergent, then it follows that the mapping is bounded. Otherwise, I don't know what to do ...

They recommended that I use theorem 1, but I don't know how to use it to ensure that the mapping in bounded.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the following steps: For each $n$ let $M_n=\{x^{*} \in X^{*}: |\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m} x^{*}(x_n)| \leq n \forall m\}$. Note that each element of $X^{*}$ belongs to $\cup_n M_n$ because the sequence of partial sums of the series $\sum x^{*}(x_n)$ is a bounded sequence. Verify that each $M_n$ is closed in $X^{*}$. Since $X^{*}$ is always complete (even if $X$ is not!) it follows by Theorem 1 that the set $M_n$ has an interior point for some $n$. Suppose $B(x_0^{*},r) \subset M_n$. Then show that $|\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} x^{*}(x_n)| \leq 2n$ whenever $\|x^{*}\|< r$. [For this write $x^{*}$ as $(x^{*}+x_0^{*})-x_0^{*}$].  Now you can easily finish the proof.

Comment: Let $$M_{n}=\{x^{*}\in X^{*}:\phantom{a}\left|\sum_{k=1}^{m}{x^{*}(x_{n})}\right|\leq n,\phantom{a}\forall m\in\mathbb{N}\}.$$ be. Let's see that $M_{n}$ is closed in $X^{*}.$ Let $x^{*}\in X^{*}\setminus{M_{n}}.$ Then exists $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $$\left|\sum_{k=1}^{m}{x^{*}(x_{n})}\right|>n.$$ Then $$n<\left|\sum_{k=1}^{m}{x^{*}(x_{n})}\right|\leq\sum_{k=1}^{m}{|x^{*}(x_{n})|}\leq |x^{*}|\sum_{k=1}^{m}{||x_{n}||}.$$ Let $M=\sum_{k=1}^{m}{||x_{n}||}>0.$ Then $$x^{*}\in X^{*}\setminus{B\left[0^{*},\dfrac{n}{M}\right]}\subseteq{X\setminus{M_{n}}}.$$ Is that correct?

Comment: Let $x^{*}\in X^{*},$ with $x^{*}\neq 0^{*}.$ Then $z^{*}=x_{0}^{*}+\dfrac{rx^{*}}{2||x^{*}||}\in B(x_{0}^{*},r)$ and $x^{*}=\dfrac{2||x^{*}||}{r}(z^{*}-x_{0}^{*}).$ Then $$|T(x^{*})|\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{|x^{*}(x_{n})|}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\dfrac{2||x^{*}||}{r}|z^{*}(x_{n})-x_{0}^{*}(x_{n})|}\leq\dfrac{2||x^{*}||}{r}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(|z^{*}(x_{n})|+|x_{0}^{*}(x_{n})|)}\leq \dfrac{4n||x^{*}||}{r}.$$ Then $$|T|\leq \dfrac{4n}{r},\phantom{a}\forall x^{*}\in X^{*}$$ and T is bounded. Is that correct?

Comment: In the second part you cannot use $\sum |
x^{*}(x_n)|$ etc; the absolute value sign has to be outside  the sum. I don't quite understand how you obtained $\subseteq X^{*} \setminus M_n$ in the first part. Some clean up is needed in this part too.

Comment: How would you argue that those $M_{n}$ are closed? I was thinking of using sequences, but I don't know how to conclude...Regarfind the second part, I think I can do that since the norm of a normed space is always continuos.

Comment: @Darkmaster If $|\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m} x_j^{*}(x_n)| \leq n \forall m$ and $x_j^{*} \to x^{*}$ then $|\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m} x^{*}(x_n)| \leq n \forall m$ (since there is only  a finite sum for each fixed $m$). This proves that $M_n$ is closed. Bringing in $|x^{*}(x_n)|$ would  make the proof completely invalid, so absolute value has to be outside the sum.